# What is a macro-function?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl

I was playing around with macros today and saw the term macro-function appear in the REPL. I am familiar with Macros, compiler macros and reader macros but have not run into these.

```
CL-USER> (defmacro fnaa (&rest rest) `(lambda ,@rest))
  FNAA

CL-USER> #'fnaa
  #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST SB-C::ARGS) :IN MACRO-FUNCTION) {1003A6DD6B}>
```

I inspected 'fnaa and got this:

```
#<SYMBOL {1003A40A5F}>
--------------------
Its name is: "FNAA"
It is unbound.
It a macro with macro-function: #<FUNCTION (MACRO-FUNCTION FNAA) {1003A610BB}>
It is internal to the package: COMMON-LISP-USER 
Property list: NIL
```

I have read [this from the CLHS](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/acc_macro-function.html) but couldn't understand what it was and what it does

Any help illuminating macro-function's purpose would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]
It seems from reading [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_m.htm#macro_function) that the function implements the expansion? Well that makes sense as a macro is really just a function that runs at macro-expansion time (and results in code) but if that is correct then why the terminology of *"a macro with macro-function"*?

I feel close but I'm still not quite getting it

[EDIT AGAIN]
Ok so looking at the [definition for macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_m.htm#macro) I get this

```
macro n. 1. a macro form 2. a macro function. 3. a macro name.
```

So is the macro the combination of these and thus the macro-function is just the implementation?

[EDIT MORE]
Given the above, the [CLHS entry for defmacro](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_defmacro.html) seems to make sense. Would anyone be able to confirm if I am on the right track here and also if it is possible to have a macro without a macro-function as, if not then I don't understand why it specifies the fact that it is a 'macro with a macro-function'

[FINAL EDIT]
Is a macro a symbol with the function slot bound to a macro-function? (this wording is crap I could do with help here!)

```
CL-USER> (setf (macro-function 'jam) (lambda (x y) nil))
```

Inspect 'jam

```
#<SYMBOL {100400317F}>
--------------------
Its name is: "JAM"
It is a global variable bound to: NIL [unbind]
It a macro with macro-function: #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X Y)) {1005522FAB}> [unbind]
It is internal to the package: COMMON-LISP-USER [export] [unintern]
Property list: NIL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `macro-function` is the function which is called on the code during macroexpansion and implements the macro.

See also [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505038/inspect-common-lisp-macro-source/17581037#17581037).

Comment: Cheers, I had read your other answer before but couldn't understand it before this little adventure :) Just to clarify then the concept of a 'macro without a macro-function' doesn't make much sense then?

Comment: @Baggers: 'macro without a macro-function' makes as much sense as 'function without a function definition' :-)